# Hide menu in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, nav

I use a master page (`Frontend.mater`) in my aspx site that consists of a tree view menu.
My problem is that one of my pages is my login page to the site which currently includes this master page (template).
My sense is that my menu to the rest of my pages should only be seen AFTER a verified login.

Is there a way that I can:
1) Hide an entire treeview menu for this login page while keeping other controls, css, and scripts for the page.
2) Is it a matter of creating a second Frontend.master file for the login page with an empty  section?
3) Other considerations?

Comment: If your treeview menu is derived from `Control`, it will have a `Visible` property, which you simply set to false in case the current page is the login page.

Comment: by empty I mean empty <nav> section.

Comment: how is that "<nav>" section embedded in your markup? is it not part of server side controls, so you could just hide it as a whole, without breaking the layout? show us markup and code.